# Android OREO - java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-8.0-oreo

I followed the below tutorial and modified code
https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/fixing-securityexception-requiring-a-valid-contentprovider-on-android-8-1110d840522

I defined the provider in the manifest file.

```
<provider
    android:name="com.test.PhotoProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.PhotoProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>

provider paths has the below line

<external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="/" />

I’m loading the uri using below code

   Uri decodedImgUri = PhotoProvider.getPhotoUri(new File(imgPath));
   ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
   cr.notifyChange(decodedImgUri, null);
   ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(decodedImgUri.toString(), holder.image);

public static Uri getPhotoUri(File file) {
    Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .authority(CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY)
            .scheme("file")
            .path(outputUri.getPath())
            .query(outputUri.getQuery())
            .fragment(outputUri.getFragment());

    return builder.build();
}
```

This is how I defined my authority

```
public static final String CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.test.PhotoProvider";
```

But when I ‘m trying to load the uri into an image view, I keep getting the below error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: com.test.PhotoProvider/data/user/0/com.test/cache/cropped953508219.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is happening even on < 8.0 version.

Comment: Hey Rajesh, seems like the application does not have permission to access storage. Can you please confirm if you are using versions above Marshmallow? If yes, you will need to request permission from user dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...
In manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.xyz.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

and In xml/provider_path file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="Android/data/com.your.package/" name="files_root"/>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Hope it will help...!